# Como fazer esse efeito com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou estudando ainda Javascript e um amigo meu me apresentou um site que tem um efeito bem legal em seus textos.

O site é esse: [(site do exemplo)](http://pizzeriadomjuan.com.br/)

Como podemos perceber, quando o site carrega, ele dá um efeito em que os elementos vão se formando na tela. Isso eu sei fazer.

Mas fazendo uma rolagem para baixo, ao chegar em certas alturas do site, alguns outros textos vão surgindo. Gostaria de saber como esse efeito foi feito.

Comment: [Esse aqui?](https://revolution.themepunch.com/jquery/) Tem um exemplos nessa página ai, vc pode usar sem o wordpress.. Veja em *Usage Examples*

Comment: Nicolas, acho que a galera tá negativando sua pergunta porque o link que você colocou ai está fora do ar.... Tenta corrigir

Comment: Obrigado por avisar! Nem sei o que tinha acontecido, mas arrumei o link

Comment: Arrumou e testou?

Comment: Ele digitou errado: é http://pizzariadomjuan.com.br/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Ele te entrega várias classes css prontas para fazer essas animações.

- Basta baixar o plugin(é apenas um arquivo css).
- Apontar ele no seu index.html `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/animate.css">`
- Na sua div você acrescenta as classes `animated animação-desejada`.

Ex: `<div class="animated fadeInUp"></div>`

Acesse: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Caso não queira baixar o plugin, pode acessar via CDN. Basta adiciona-lo no seu index.html.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">`

Para adicionar o efeito de acordo com a altura do scrollbar, faça:

**JS** (utilizando jquery)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= 500) { //você escolhe o valor que desejar
      $("#seuElemento").addClass("animated fadeInUp");
   }
});
```

Comment: Nossa, realmente esse arquivo é um ótimo quebra galho. Mas e no caso da ativação somente quando a barra de rolagem está em certa altura do site. Como fazer?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Confere ai =)

Comment: Ae Amigo! Ajudou bastante aqui, já consegui fazer o efeito que queria e ainda descobri vários outros né :)